# Scale vector of numbers with right proportions

Tags: vectors

If I have a vector of numbers $[-4,3,1,0.1,7]$, how do I scale this vector so that the smallest value becomes $-1$, the largest value becomes $1$, and the remaining numbers are adjusted so that the proportions are preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector that you obtain is obviously not in the same direction in $R^k$
but you can do it this way:
$$
v=2\cdot\frac{x-\rm{min}}{\rm{max}-\rm{min}}-1
$$
in this case:
$$
v=2\cdot\frac{x+4}{11}-1
$$
now for all elements set $x$ to the value in your vector and $v$ is the new value you are seeking.
if you want arbitrary limits $a\to b$:
$$
v=(b-a)\cdot\frac{x-\rm{min}}{\rm{max}-\rm{min}}+a
$$

Comment: What if I want to change the 'limits', so that it is no longer -1 and 1, but instead 50 and 150? Is it possible to adjust the function to this?

Comment: read now. and +1 if you are satisfied ;)

Comment: Great!! Thanks! The only problem is when $max=min$. What do I do about that?